# value is not getting assigned inside the while loop

Tags: linux, shell, unix

below is my code. Here i'm replacing 2nd column which is having value as "1" to "1AM" but it's not working.

```
#! /bin/ksh

file="TOTAL_SALES_UNITS_ORDERS_SORTDATA1.txt"
while IFS=":" read f1 f2 f3 f4 f5
do
if [[ $f2 -eq '1' ]];
then
print $f2
f2="1AM"
print $f2
fi
    IFS=":"
done < "$file"
```

the expected result is column 2 is to updates as 1AM, where the value is 1.
but the file is not getting updated, the echo value shows 1AM but file has value "1".

Is there a anything wrong in the code? please guide thanks in advance!

Comment: It did not update the file because you did not put any code to update the file.. Try changing `print $f2` to `print $f1:$f2:$f3:$f4:$f5 > out.txt`

Answer (score 0):

So you want to conditionally change the second column in a `:`-delimited file from `1` to `1AM`?

You can do this easily with, for example, `awk`:

```
$ cat testdata
foo:bar:quux:one:two
foo:1:quux:one:two

$ awk 'BEGIN { OFS=FS=":" } { if ($2 == "1") $2 = "1AM"; print }' < testdata > newdata
$ cat newdata
foo:bar:quux:one:two
foo:1AM:quux:one:two
```